# How to fail jenkins job if the sonar project does not pass Quality gate stage

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run my sonar scanner from jenkins and I want my jenkins job to fail when the Quality gate at sonar is not met.
I have configured sonar host and sonar scanner with jenkins at global tool level, my project analysis is uploaded in sonar, but the jenkins job is still passing. what am i doing wrong.
so, basically I am trying to achieve this https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/ , I can do it via pipelines, but I want to achieve the same thing via a jenkins job.
Here is my job
just clone a project and run sonar scanner.
this is the build step

```
git clone 'https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples.git # clone
cd $WORKSPACE   # goto cloned workspace
```

Here are the properties passed to sonarscanner

```
Analysis properties:

    sonar.projectKey=org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner
    sonar.java.binaries=.
    sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

I believe `sonar.qualitygate.wait=true` this is the extra step that  I need to do at sonar scanner step.
I want my jenkins job to fail, as soon as Quality gate fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar issue. the wait for sonar quality gate in order to break the Jenkins build

I achieved this by adding `-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.qualitygate.timeout=300` to the command launching the sonar scanner

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.qualitygate.timeout=300 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding='UTF-8' -Dsonar.projectKey=${projectKeyAndName} -Dsonar.projectName=${projectKeyAndName} -Dsonar.branchname=${env.BRANCH_NAME}
```